# How to show approved or public subscriptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following models and relations between them:

```
App
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
User
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
Subscription
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :app

# Table name: subscriptions
#
#  app_id     :integer
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  approved   :boolean
#
# Table name: apps
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  user_id    :integer
#  private    :boolean
#
# Table name: users
#
#  app_id     :integer
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
```

I would like to show only approved Subscriptions or public apps(where `private` is false) which are subscribed.

```
  # user.rb < this is only for approved but how to add here also public subscribed apps
  def approved_or_public_subscriptions
    subscriptions.where(approved: true)
  end
```

Comment: you should use a scope, something like this: `scope :approved, where(approved: true)` (in the `Subscription.rb` and then start from your user: `@current_user.subscriptions.approved #=> returns an array of the user's subscriptions AND approved = true`

Comment: Ok, but how to handle with ``app.private == false`` in subscription scope ?

Comment: `scope :approved, joins(:app).where(approved: true, private: false)` (if doesnt work, try to `joins(:apps)`. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: I receive following error in console: https://gist.github.com/2523db7309eb335feddf should be ``joins(:app)``

Comment: Oh i see, `[blablabla] AND "subscriptions"."approved" = 't' AND "subscriptions"."private" = 'f' ` : Its trying to find a subscriptions that is private instead of Apps. Try this: `scope :approved, joins(:app).where("subscriptions.approved = 't' AND apps.private = 'f'")`

Comment: Hmm, yest but I had to change that scope to: ``scope :approved_or_public, joins(:app).where('subscriptions.approved = true OR apps.private = false')``

Comment: ok good that you found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scope:

```
scope :approved_or_public, joins(:app).where('subscriptions.approved = true OR apps.private = false')
```